# Working with two fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-listfragment

There are two fragments. However it is slightly different from the tutorials case when there is one ListFragment and one DetailFrament, because I have two ListFragments. Now the problems is when I use this in one fragment :

```
getListView().addFooter(someView);
```

It would automatically assign this footer (or header) to another fragment as well, because getListView() method "Gets the activity's list view widget" and my two ListFragments are both in the main activity.

Any ideas how to get around it???

Comment: From what context do you call getListView?

Comment: From the onActivityCreated method of my ListFragment. it is like this ListView lv = getListView(); or ListView lv = this.getListView();

Comment: It's a bit strange that it's added on both ListViews, as only one object is returned :/

Comment: I can't help you without more code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uhu solved.

The problem was that one of my fragments was actually called "ListFragment" and at some point my fragment and the actual class ListFragment were confused and it caused a problem.

I took this idea from [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/Android/article.html) but it seems that that guy has already tweaked it for the better. Anyway I shall punch him in the face on the first occasion.

Answer (score 0):

Considered having a reference to you listview by an id in the xml? Then you could find the listview in oncreate and do something like following:

```
myListView.addFooter(someView);
```